# The language of Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, area-51, stack-exchange, languages

I've seen in Area 51 an awful lot of plans to split this community, especially Stack Overflow. Sites about the very same thing in [different languages](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=stackoverflow+languages). It's like using categories instead of tags; it splits the community into groups with little traffic, similarly to what you have in the MSDN Forums.

Nonetheless I understand wanting to have the site in your own language, to act as a break to anglophonic imperialism (that's what it is). So I suggest giving Esperanto a try on the Stack Exchange network. Before you downvote (metas do often kill minorities), consider an analogy with fossil fuels and renewable energies such as hydrogen combustion.

Perhaps some of the non-language related sites should allow English and Esperanto, and language related sites should allow the language they're about plus a bit of these two.

Comment: @Oded, I'm just throwing ideas on StackExchange. Although I can make a discussion to merge other language's StackOverflows, for example.

Comment: [StackOverflow is already available in Esperanto](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=eo&u=http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186000/the-language-of-stackexchange&usg=ALkJrhhXckZQA5PStnZzSiGPlNatUHGY0Q). Kind of.

Comment: So you're saying to make SO itself Esperanto in addition to English? That's seems utterly pointless. Even more so considering the fact that programming happens almost exclusively in English. And I'm of the opinion that any aspiring programmer better learn the language. If you're merely proposing an SO-like site in Esperanto, take it to Area51.

Comment: Google Translate? No.

Comment: You lost me at "anglophonic imperialism".

Comment: @Bart, I don't want to divide the community even further. What I might try to do is propose that joining all other different language StackOverflows in one; however, that's a battle I won't win.

Comment: @JMCF125 They are proposals. That's all. If they can get a significant user base and get to Beta (let alone graduate from Beta), good for them. The idea that Esperanto will be this great unifier however does not seem to be grounded in reality.

Comment: Too late boy, English is already well-established as the dominant language of programming. Nationalism & Imperialism, that's what we do. We plan to invade the world soon. Oh wait, is that your country's flag on your profile picture ? Say no to Esperanto imperialism. http://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Meds, no, it's other flag, go figure out. And FYI, English language is multiplying into new languages for such a big amount of irregularities. In 200 years, it simply won't exist.

Comment: I'll let this cool down and come back later. DON'T delete it while I'm gone. :)

Comment: I think you mean __anglophonic superiority__.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A language's main mission is to help people communicate (join rather than separate or divide). I understand that people would prefer a SO site on their language (I'm spanish), but in this case it's the opposite to the Divide and Conquer algorithm.

In this case, dividing the manpower into groups means a loss in every sense. If I have a question I would make an effort to ask it in the main (english) SO site, because it would really be easier to get a good answer.

This is not a negative to a minority, but an invitation to keep together because this is what makes SO great.

**UPDATE:**

> ... anglophonic imperialism...
>
> ---
>
> ... old imperialism...
>
> ---
>
> English language is multiplying into new languages for such a big
> amount of irregularities. In 200 years, it simply won't exist.
>
> ---
>
> ... whoever has the biggest stable economy, exerts the most influence in
> the world culture (especially now with globalization); the french, the
> british and the german were there, and now it's the american's turn
> (not for long though).
>
> ---
>
> Communication should be fair, equal to both sides, and if someone
> refuses to use other languages; you simply can't say it to be fair.
> It's a culture smashing all others in a certain environment; like a
> big company, who buys smaller ones and sends thousands to
> unemployment. Sorry, I'm diverging; but I think you get the analogy.
> It is important to respect culture; Esperanto has a culture including
> such mutual respect. English doesn't.

@JMCF125, don't you think this has gotten out of hand? It's getting really off-topic. In other Q&A sites ([politics.stackexchange.com](http://politics.stackexchange.com)), this could be discussed and you would probably get upvoted, but this is not the place to discuss about the roundness of Earth. English is nowadays the best language to get the highest number of programmers to share their knowledge and expertise. And this is our big treasure: **sharing knowledge**. Creating a big messed up site with multiple languages is not the solution but a problem for this. I could agree with you in many of your statements, but SO is not the place to fight your battle.

P.S. As I said, I'm spanish. Spain is a country with 5 co-official languages, which some people continuously try to use ones against the others using similar arguments to yours. Likewise, Spain is a country with a history of colonialism and world domination (["The empire on which the sun never sets"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_empire_on_which_the_sun_never_sets)). Also, I'm from the Canary Islands, where the spanish came and nearly extinguish our people ([Guanches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanches)), our culture and our language ([Guanche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanche_language) or [Tamazight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamazight)).

I know what you are talking about, but this is simply not the place. IMHO, a multi-language main SO site is a really ugly and pointless solution.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I invoked the minorities as justification for the downvotes I was sure to see in no-time. 1500 hours of learning English is equivalent to 150 hours of learning Esperanto, BTW (you can Google that if you don't trust me).

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I understand you, but I totally disagree with you. Google how many english speakers are out there vs Esperanto speakers and you will get a big bunch of people that don't even need those 1500 hours to learn english or that have already dedicated them. English is and will keep being for long time the default language, especially when we talk about programming languages.

Comment: Ah, so you've found the problem. (and I supposed you didn't vote at all, you seem a nice disagreeing guy:) ) They haven't got to learn any other language; while we must. It's old imperialism, it's just wrong (although they're the ones who stay ignorant). +1, BTW (now I can't again, my reputation is floating like a paper boat in the middle of a storm).

Comment: @JMCF125, don't be paranoic, we have a democracy. You can create a proposal for Stackoverflow in Esperanto and see if there will be more people to use it than the Stackoverflow in English.

Comment: I have no problem with that "old imperialism" you talk about. It's language, it's to communicate. If I could I would learn all the languages on earth, but I can't so an effort to learn english is simply common sense.

Comment: @Tomas, of course there won't. At least, for the next fifty years (and that's optimistic). Let's face it, whoever has the biggest stable economy, exerts the most influence in the world culture (especially now with globalization); the french, the british and the german were there, and now it's the american's turn (not for long though). In today's society (and I mean almost worldwide), it's basically impossible for such a project to succeed. I'll try anyway, but this is fact.

Comment: If I could learn all the languages I'd learn them too. I can't though. It's better, however, to learn some than none. And most of native English speakers know none. Communication should be fair, equal to both sides, and if someone refuses to use other languages; you simply can't say it to be fair. It's a culture smashing all others in a certain environment; like a big company, who buys smaller ones and sends thousands to unemployment. Sorry, I'm diverging; but I think you get the analogy. It is important to respect culture; Esperanto has a culture including such mutual respect. English doesn't

Comment: Sorry, I did diverge a little. But it's tagged as discussion. I posted it here because I think it is quite general, however, my justifications became more stressed than what they justified. It was just a discussion, and I didn't mean to create "a big messed up site with multiple languages". I was just trying to find a fairer way to share knowledge (which by itself would create more knowledge). Let this post be a mark for people with crazy ideas like me. :) Also, I think some of your first arguments are discussable, but as you said, I've already gone off-topic. Thank you for your time.

Comment: OF COURSE my arguments are discussable. StackOverflow is so great that even @JonSkeet can be downvoted ;)

Comment: While rereading this, I remember I did post something related on Politics SE. They basically kicked me out (I deleted my account). It happened to many good questions there, it seems they only care about american loony laws (seeing the average upvoted questions there). They're even more pragmatist than here. No point taking any ideas there... BTW, I did make that (unsuccessful, as I predicted) [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58547/stack-overflow-en-esperanto?referrer=TEJsWtMJQRs07fKN243vDA2) on Area51.

Answer (score 7):

Feel free to propose "Stack Overflow in Esperanto" [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology). Language-specific sites are allowed ([like](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) [one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) [and](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish) [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54232/stack-overflow-in-german) [one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/56923/stack-overflow-in-polish) [and](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47205/stack-overflow-in-chinese) [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50998/stack-overflow-in-french) [one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36546/stack-overflow-in-hindi) [and](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36429/stack-overflow-in-italian) [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40653/stack-overflow-in-persian) [one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54441/stack-overflow-in-korean) [and also this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47783/super-user-in-german)). There is some work to be done before SE can be fully internationalized (which is why the proposals like the Portuguese one are on hold), but if you can get enough support for a proposal, then a site will eventually get created.

However, if you're proposing that all current sites allow Esperanto, that just won't work. People won't be able to understand each other, and there will be a divide in the community. If you want SE to be in Esperanto, you have to ask for a separate Esperanto site.

Comment: What I'd like to do is to join all those different languages StackOverflow proposals into one (in Esperanto); and in really long term join that with this StackOverflow. The same for other proposals with different languages.

Comment: @JMCF125 don't you realize that this simply won't work, because people don't know Esperanto? *English* is our Esperanto. So what your propose is in fact already done, with language far more spread than Esperanto and generally accepted as *lingua franca*.

Comment: @JMCF125 Like Bart mentioned, Esperanto is not the great unifier you think it is. Currently, it's not being used as a "universal language" much, and I don't see that changing. The closest we have to a universal language is _English_, because it's taught in many other countries. The reason these proposals sprouted up was that many people aren't good at English, and prefer their mothertongue. Now, switch over to Esperanto, a language that most haven't even _heard_ of, and it's much worse.

Answer (score 4):

Let's not do something like that. Having users appropriately use a single agreed upon language on a site is already a hassle. Let's not introduce other languages into the mix. Not even something like Esperanto. Let's be honest here, Esperanto is not the great unifier you think it will be.

When it comes to programming, English is simply the default language. Most programming languages use it. And I'm of the opinion that any aspiring programmer better pick up the language. I do understand the desire to have a Stack Overflow in your first language. It's difficult if your ideas are clear but you can't express them.

One thing to keep in mind is that the Area51 proposals are just that: proposals. There is no guarantee that any of them will ever see the light of day. Merely reaching the Beta stage will be hard for them, and graduating from that even harder. If they do, they have proven themselves. Good luck to them.

But using multiple languages on a single site should simply not be done. It's confusing, dividing, and will do more harm than good.

Comment: "the great unifier you think it will be": no I didn't say it would be a unifier, just read my last comments above. I'm, again, just discussing some ideas on SE in general.