# Is there a Stack Exchange site for philosophy in French?

Tags: discussion, localization, languages

Is there a Stack Exchange site for philosophy in French? If not, what about adding one? In a broader scope, is there a plan to add site in each language on each topic of Stack Overflow?

Comment: New sites are proposed and discussed on Area 51; this probably belongs at [Area 51 Discussion](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/) (and, of course, just search Area 51 for your site).

Comment: You have [French Language & Usage](http://french.stackexchange.com/) and you have [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/), not one site for both.

Comment: philosophy.SE barely has a large enough audience in English to sustain itself (2.2 questions per day.) I suspect the audience in French would be even smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Current list of Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

The process for getting a new Stack Exchange site created is detailed at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). By using this process it can be illustrated that there is a need for a site covering a particular topic and that it will get enough use and traffic to justify its existence.

No, there's not a plan to add sites for every topic in every language. There just wouldn't be enough use.

And these *are not* forums.

Answer (score 0):

[These](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186000/the-language-of-stack-exchange?rq=1) focus on StackOverFlow, but I feel they're applicable in this case as well. Unless there is something significant to be gained from have a topic in a specific language (perhaps a French version of the `English Language and Usage`), you're just dividing up your audience and catering to a small portion of them.

Comment: In this case, dividing your audience would mean that no French speaker who don't speak English have interest in philosophy. I gonna look at Area51, thank for all your answers.